# Date incremental from a defined date in php

Tags: php, loops, date

how to continuously adding one month to a given date (like continous looping),

see scenero below

```
given this $original_date is  30-7-2019   ,  echo 30-8-2019        //$original_date  + 1

when current date is > 30-8-2019 ,    echo 30-9-2019  i.e add one month to last
when current date is > 30-9-2019 ,    echo 30-10-2019 i.e add one month to last
when current date is > 30-10-2019 , echo 30-11-2019 i.e add one month to last
when current date is > 30-11-2019 , echo 30-12-2019 i.e add one month to last
```

and so on

I got the difference between current date and the given date and always adding the difference to every current daye

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$given_date= date('2019-6-29');
//echo $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($given_date)));

//get month difference function
function getyearDiff($date){
            $today = new DateTime();
            $date = new DateTime($date);
            $interval = $date->diff($today);
            return $interval->format("%r%m");   
        }

//get month difference and remove negative if it exist
$diif =  abs(getyearDiff($filling_period)) ;
//echo $diif;

//add the difference
echo $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$diif.' month', strtotime($filling_period)));
```

always add one month to the expected date from a given date

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is _way_ too unclear. You need to explain what your _issue_ is. Not just what you want and what you got. We're not going to guess what the problem is.

Comment: @quickSwap. how to continuously adding one month to a given date (like continous looping), read above

Answer (score 1):

[Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9f5738c3b98a976c11af46ab180b3d41a658eb6c)

Here is snippet you can try

```
$today = new DateTime();
$given_date= new DateTime('2019-06-29');
$period = new DatePeriod( // create period instance between today and given date
     $today,
     new DateInterval('P1M'), // continously add one month difference
     $given_date
);
foreach( $period as $date) { 
   echo $date->format('Y-m-d').'<br/>'; 
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: This is good, but i need to pass conditional statement like at such new date, keeps adding one month

Comment: Until what? There much some limit? Keep adding to infinity is not possible,you should clear your question precisely.

Comment: not untill infinity, what it simply means is, when the defined date is met eg, 20-2-2019, echo 20-3-2019, when 20-3-2019 is met, echo 20-4-2019, when 20-4-2019 is met, echo 20-5-2019................so there is always a condition of echo next month date when current month date is met

Comment: Check my answer now

Comment: What happens when you add one month to 31st January? Do you get 31st February? Or 3rd March (or 2nd every fourth year)? Or should you get 28th February? Add another month and now what do you get? Is that date really two months from when you started?